# Understanding the definition of arbitrage opportunities (one period model)

Tags: probability-theory, finance

The setting is the one period model of a financial market with $d+1$ assets, where the $0$-th asset is a riskless bond:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $\overline\pi \in \mathbb{R}_+^{d+1}$ be an initial price vector with $\pi^0 := 1$. Let $\overline S:=(S^0,S^1,\dots,S^d)$ be the final price vector, where $S^0 \equiv 1+r, r>-1$ and $S^i, i \ge 1$ are non-negative RVs. At inital time, a portfolio $\overline\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ can be chosen. $\overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi$ is the initial price of the porfolio, $\overline\xi \cdot \overline S$ is the final value of the portfolio, where the dot denotes the standard inner product.

> **Definition:** $\overline\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ is an *arbitrage opportunity*, if
>
> $\quad$**1.** $\overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi \le 0$,
>
> $\quad$**2.** $\mathbb{P}(\overline\xi \cdot \overline S \ge 0 ) = 1$
> and
>
> $\quad$**3.** $\mathbb{P}(\overline\xi \cdot \overline S > 0 ) > 0$.

[The book](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110463453/html) summarizes the definition as follows:

> Intuitively, an arbitrage opportunity is an investment strategy that yields with
> strictly positive probability a strictly positive profit and is not
> exposed to any downside risk.

But if I had to make this "intuitive" definition precise, I would rather drop the first requirement and replace $\overline\xi \cdot \overline S$ by $\overline\xi \cdot \overline S-\overline\xi \cdot \overline \pi$ in the second and third requirement. What is wrong with my understanding of the model?

Comment: The 'intuitively (...)' citation does not mention (1). It should add that an arbitrage has zero or negative initial cost (i.e. someone pays you to have it).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the authors way of saying

$$\overline S \cdot \overline\xi \ge \overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi$$

with an arbitrary $0$ point between them.

Comment: I have thought about the issue and I don't think that the requirement is "arbitrary". If I am not mistaken, then the truth value of $\xi\cdot\pi< \xi\cdot S$ depends on the chosen numéraire, whereas if the stronger requirement $\xi\cdot\pi\leq 0<\xi\cdot S$ is true w.r.t. one numéraire, then it is true w.r.t. all numéraires. What do you think?

Comment: In addition, if we pick one of the assets as numéraire, then the existence of a $\xi$ such that $\xi\cdot\pi<\xi\cdot S$ turns out to be equivalent to the existence of a $\xi$ such that $\xi\cdot\pi\leq 0<\xi\cdot S$.

Comment: Personally, I thought $\pi$ was a cost, hence negative (money out), and the author was defining 'arbitrage' as a strict turn around in value, but then I thought this is very naïve. so that the $0$ must be a benchmark of sorts.

Comment: The assets are assumed to be non-negative (w.r.t. one and hence w.r.t to all numéraires). But short sales are allowed.